# Spring Cloud Gateway in Docker Compose returns ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud

I'm building a microservices app and I've run into problem with configuring the Spring Cloud gateway to proxy the calls to the API from frontend running on Nginx server.

When I make a POST request to `/users/login`, I get this response: `OPTIONS http://28a41511677e:8082/login net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.
The string `28a41511677e` is the services docker container ID. When I call another service (using GET method), it returns data just fine.

I'm using Eureka discovery server which seems to find all the services correctly. The service in question is registered as `28a41511677e:users-service:8082`

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    build: db/
    expose:
      - 5432

  registry:
    build: registryservice/
    expose:
      - 8761
    ports:
      - 8761:8761

  gateway:
    build: gatewayservice/
    expose:
      - 8080
    depends_on:
      - registry

  users:
    build: usersservice/
    expose:
      - 8082
    depends_on:
      - registry
      - db

  timetable:
    build: timetableservice/
    expose:
      - 8081
    depends_on:
      - registry
      - db

  ui:
    build: frontend/
    expose:
      - 80
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - gateway
```

Gateway implementation:

```java
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayserviceApplication {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes()
                .route("users-service", p -> p.path("/user/**")
                        .uri("lb://users-service"))
                .route("timetable-service", p -> p.path("/routes/**")
                        .uri("lb://timetable-service"))
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Gateway settings:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service

  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - DELETE

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://registry:8761/eureka
```

Users service controller:

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/login")
    ResponseEntity<Long> login(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) {
        logger.info("Logging in user");
        Long uid = userService.logIn(loginDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(uid, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Edit:
This also happens on NPM dev server. I tried changing the `lb://users-service` to `http://users:8082`, with no success, still getting `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

I however found that when I call the endpoint, the following output can be seen in log:

```
gateway_1    | 2019-05-19 23:55:10.842  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
gateway_1    | 2019-05-19 23:55:10.866  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
gateway_1    | 2019-05-19 23:55:10.867  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
gateway_1    | 2019-05-19 23:55:10.868  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
gateway_1    | 2019-05-19 23:55:10.868  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
gateway_1    | 2019-05-19 23:55:10.869  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: false
gateway_1    | 2019-05-19 23:55:10.871  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
gateway_1    | 2019-05-19 23:55:11.762  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:19.268  INFO 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:19.273  INFO 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:19.513  INFO 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 239 ms
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:20.563  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:20.565  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:20.565  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:20.566  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:20.566  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:20.566  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: false
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:20.567  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
users_1      | 2019-05-19 21:55:20.958  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
```

Edit 2:
I enabled logging for the gateway service and this is the output whenever I call `/user/login`. According to the logs, the gateway matches the `/users/login/` correctly, but then starts using just `/login` for some reason.

```
2019-05-20 12:58:47.002 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xff6d8305, L:/172.19.0.4:8080 - R:/172.19.0.7:42958] New http connection, requesting read
2019-05-20 12:58:47.025 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0xff6d8305, L:/172.19.0.4:8080 - R:/172.19.0.7:42958] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-05-20 12:58:47.213 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xff6d8305, L:/172.19.0.4:8080 - R:/172.19.0.7:42958] Increasing pending responses, now 1
2019-05-20 12:58:47.242 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer     : [id: 0xff6d8305, L:/172.19.0.4:8080 - R:/172.19.0.7:42958] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@575e590e
2019-05-20 12:58:47.379 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.f.WeightCalculatorWebFilter      : Weights attr: {}
2019-05-20 12:58:47.817 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : RouteDefinition CompositeDiscoveryClient_USERS-SERVICE applying {pattern=/USERS-SERVICE/**} to Path
2019-05-20 12:58:47.952 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : RouteDefinition CompositeDiscoveryClient_USERS-SERVICE applying filter {regexp=/USERS-SERVICE/(?<remaining>.*), replacement=/${remaining}} to RewritePath
2019-05-20 12:58:47.960 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : RouteDefinition matched: CompositeDiscoveryClient_USERS-SERVICE
2019-05-20 12:58:47.961 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : RouteDefinition CompositeDiscoveryClient_GATEWAY-SERVICE applying {pattern=/GATEWAY-SERVICE/**} to Path
2019-05-20 12:58:47.964 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : RouteDefinition CompositeDiscoveryClient_GATEWAY-SERVICE applying filter {regexp=/GATEWAY-SERVICE/(?<remaining>.*), replacement=/${remaining}} to RewritePath
2019-05-20 12:58:47.968 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : RouteDefinition matched: CompositeDiscoveryClient_GATEWAY-SERVICE
2019-05-20 12:58:47.979 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.h.p.RoutePredicateFactory        : Pattern "/user/**" matches against value "/user/login"
2019-05-20 12:58:47.980 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: users-service
2019-05-20 12:58:47.981 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: POST http://gateway:8080/user/login] to Route{id='users-service', uri=lb://users-service, order=0, predicate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils$$Lambda$333/0x000000084035ac40@276b060f, gatewayFilters=[]}
2019-05-20 12:58:47.981 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [ff6d8305] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@4faea64b
2019-05-20 12:58:47.994 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted gatewayFilterFactories: [OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@773f7880}, order=-2147482648}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@65a4798f}, order=-1}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@4c51bb7}, order=0}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@878452d}, order=10000}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter@4f2613d1}, order=10100}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@83298d7}, order=2147483646}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@6d24ffa1}, order=2147483647}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@426b6a74}, order=2147483647}]
2019-05-20 12:58:47.996 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter   : RouteToRequestUrlFilter start
2019-05-20 12:58:47.999 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter  : LoadBalancerClientFilter url before: lb://users-service/user/login
2019-05-20 12:58:48.432  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: users-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2019-05-20 12:58:48.492  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-users-service
2019-05-20 12:58:48.496  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: users-service instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=users-service,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2019-05-20 12:58:48.506  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2019-05-20 12:58:48.543  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: users-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2019-05-20 12:58:48.555  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client users-service initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=users-service,current list of Servers=[157e1f567371:8082],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;      Instance count:1;       Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;       Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:157e1f567371:8082;     Zone:defaultZone;       Total Requests:0;       Successive connection failure:0;        Total blackout seconds:0;       Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970;      First connection made: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970;   Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0;     average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;      max resp time:0.0;      stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@3cd9b0bf
2019-05-20 12:58:48.580 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter  : LoadBalancerClientFilter url chosen: http://157e1f567371:8082/user/login
2019-05-20 12:58:48.632 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : Creating new client pool [proxy] for 157e1f567371:8082
2019-05-20 12:58:48.646 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439] Created new pooled channel, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-05-20 12:58:48.651 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0xa9634439] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (SimpleChannelPool$1#0 = io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool$1), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-05-20 12:58:48.673 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082]}, [connected])
2019-05-20 12:58:48.679 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] onStateChange(GET{uri=/, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082]}}, [configured])
2019-05-20 12:58:48.682 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Registering pool release on close event for channel
2019-05-20 12:58:48.690 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Handler is being applied: {uri=http://157e1f567371:8082/user/login, method=POST}
2019-05-20 12:58:48.701 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] New sending options
2019-05-20 12:58:48.720 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Writing object DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /user/login HTTP/1.1
content-length: 37
accept-language: cs-CZ,cs;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
referer: http://localhost/user/login
cookie: JSESSIONID=6797219EB79F6026BD8F19E9C46C09DB
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin: http://gateway:8080
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Forwarded: proto=http;host="gateway:8080";for="172.19.0.7:42958"
X-Forwarded-For: 172.19.0.1,172.19.0.7
X-Forwarded-Proto: http,http
X-Forwarded-Port: 80,8080
X-Forwarded-Host: localhost,gateway:8080
host: 157e1f567371:8082
2019-05-20 12:58:48.751 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Channel connected, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-05-20 12:58:48.759 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Writing object
2019-05-20 12:58:48.762 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0xff6d8305, L:/172.19.0.4:8080 - R:/172.19.0.7:42958] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 1, cancelled:false, inboundDone: true]
2019-05-20 12:58:48.808 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Writing object EmptyLastHttpContent
2019-05-20 12:58:48.809 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] onStateChange(POST{uri=/user/login, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082]}}, [request_sent])
2019-05-20 12:58:49.509  INFO 1 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: users-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2019-05-20 12:58:49.579 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Set-Cookie=JSESSIONID=7C47A99C1F416F910AB554F4617247D6; Path=/; HttpOnly, X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma=no-cache, Expires=0, X-Frame-Options=DENY, Location=http://157e1f567371:8082/login, Content-Length=0, Date=Mon, 20 May 2019 10:58:49 GMT]
2019-05-20 12:58:49.579 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] onStateChange(POST{uri=/user/login, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082]}}, [response_received])
2019-05-20 12:58:49.581 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter  : NettyWriteResponseFilter start
2019-05-20 12:58:49.586 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 0, cancelled:false, inboundDone: false]
2019-05-20 12:58:49.586 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Received last HTTP packet
2019-05-20 12:58:49.593 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xff6d8305, L:/172.19.0.4:8080 - R:/172.19.0.7:42958] Writing object DefaultFullHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: EmptyByteBufBE)
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7C47A99C1F416F910AB554F4617247D6; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://157e1f567371:8082/login
Date: Mon, 20 May 2019 10:58:49 GMT
content-length: 0
2019-05-20 12:58:49.595 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xff6d8305, L:/172.19.0.4:8080 - R:/172.19.0.7:42958] Detected non persistent http connection, preparing to close
2019-05-20 12:58:49.595 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xff6d8305, L:/172.19.0.4:8080 - R:/172.19.0.7:42958] Last Http packet was sent, terminating channel
2019-05-20 12:58:49.598 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] onStateChange(POST{uri=/user/login, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082]}}, [disconnecting])
2019-05-20 12:58:49.598 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Releasing channel
2019-05-20 12:58:49.598 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa9634439, L:/172.19.0.4:59624 - R:157e1f567371/172.19.0.5:8082] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
```

Comment: When I call another service (using GET method), it returns data just fine?? ```http://28a41511677e:8082/login```  from where you are making this call? from browser or from container.  Have you tried using the ip resolution instead of container name?

Comment: When I call the 'timetable' service (`/routes/stops`), it sent data back properly.
I'm making the call with AJAX from the frontend part (React) as a call to `/users/login`, this gets routed to the gateway service and then to users service. 
I think the problem is that for some reason, the `/users/` part of the URI gets lost and users service controller only receives the `/login/` part, for which it does not have an endpoint. That would make sense, since the call wakes the service up, according to the logs. I just don't see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Does your project available in github to take a look ?

Comment: Just check whether this will help [discovery locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215050/spring-cloud-gateway-auto-routing-to-eureka-services)

Comment: I've tried, I'm still getting the same result. I haven't made the code public yet, unfortunately.

Comment: share the logs of the issues/ share some screenshots or reproducible project in github to get help.

Comment: I've added a log output of the gateway service when the `/user/login` endpoind is called. I'd be happy to provide any more logs from other services, I just don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. The problem was actually not in the gateway, it was in the users service. It had improper security configuration and required a login when accessing its endpoints. So, when I called any endpoint, it got redirected to `/login`.

I added the following code to the service and it works properly now.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

That's probably not a proper solution, but on a non production code it gets the job done.