# Spring Cloud Gateway auto routing to Eureka services

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I work with Spring to create microservices. I am using Eureka for service discovery and Zuul for routing. Now I wanted to switch to Spring Cloud Gateway (because of non-blocking nature) but I've failed to figure out a way of auto routing to each Eureka service.

For example if one service 'eureka-client' registers to Eureka, Zuul does provide a path like localhost:8762/eureka-client to this service by itself. With Spring Cloud Gateway, I've to create a route all by myself for each service.

```
      routes:
      - id: eureka-client
        uri: lb://eureka-client
        predicates:
        - Path=/eureka-client/**
```

With a few services that's acceptable but I might get hundreds of services in the end. And each has to write its own route in Spring Cloud Gateway.

Is there a way to provide auto routing from Spring Cloud Gateway to each service from Eureka?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto routing can be [configured](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_discoveryclient_route_definition_locator).

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
```